# Angular add dynamic html(directive) with object as parameter

Tags: angularjs

Doesn't sound like it would be a big deal but I don't know what to google for to solve this. I want to be able to fetch an object with $http and then render that info with the help of a directive.

JS:

```
angular.module("test", []);
angular.module("test").directive('myTest', function() {
  return {
    templateUrl: 'myTest.html'
  };
});
angular.module("test").controller("myCtrl", function($http, $compile){
  var vm = this;
  vm.name = "Viktor";
  vm.country = "Sweden";
  vm.origin = "controller";
  vm.click = function(){
    $http.get("data"+Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1)+".json").success(function(data){ 
      $("body").append($compile("<my-test></my-test>")(data));
    })
  }
})
```

Template:

```
<div>
  <div>My name is: {{vm.name}}</div>
  <div>I live in : {{vm.country}}</div>
  <div>Source origin : {{vm.origin}}</div>
</div>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="test">

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@*" data-semver="1.4.7" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
    <button ng-click="vm.click()">Add panel</button>
    <my-test></my-test>
  </body>

</html>
```

Plunker: http://embed.plnkr.co/YcG9ZFxuR3PYBYASjzm2/preview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still stuck in the jQuery way of thinking, I guess I found out how to do it the Angular way. Just to add the newly fetched item to a list and then render the list. Not what I was originally aiming for but that is probably the prettiest way.

And if one now HAVE to add new items instead of redrawing the whole list, I guess one could send in the object as a json-string or set scope variables on the directive for each parameter in the object.

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/5ElTIx?p=preview

Html:

```
<body ng-controller="myCtrl as vm">
    <button ng-click="vm.click()">Add panel</button>
    <my-test ng-repeat="panel in vm.panels" obj="panel"></my-test>
</body>
```

Js:

```
angular.module("test").controller("myCtrl", function($http, $compile){
  var vm = this;
  vm.name = "Viktor";
  vm.country = "Sweden";
  vm.origin = "controller";
  vm.panels = [{
    name:"Viktor2",
    origin:"Controller array",
    country:"Sweden"
  }];
  vm.click = function(){
    $http.get("data"+Math.floor((Math.random() * 2) + 1)+".json").success(function(data){ 
      vm.panels.push({
        name:data.name,
        origin:data.origin,
        country:data.country
      })
    })
  }
})
```

Comment: Apparently the list doesnt get redrawn every time. Ben Nadel talks about it here: http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2443-rendering-dom-elements-with-ngrepeat-in-angularjs.htm

Answer (score 0):

I just can't edit your plnkr file.

But `bindToController` should help you. It should be somethind like this,  I create a controller for the directive :

```
angular.module("test").directive('myTest', function() {    
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {},
        templateUrl: 'myTest.html',
        controller: function(){},
        controllerAs: 'ctrl',
        bindToController: {
            name: '=',
            country: '=',
            origin: '='}
        }
});
```

Also I change the alias of the controller in the template :

```
<div>
  <div>My name is: {{ctrl.name}}</div>
  <div>I live in : {{ctrl.country}}</div>
  <div>Source origin : {{ctrl.origin}}</div>
  <input ng-model="ctrl.name"/>
</div>
```

Here is a working example modified on your plunkr : [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/DsDwwWMvlKulsPP3CzWs?p=preview).

Comment: I'm new to plunker, should I make it public for you to be able to edit it ?
Try this one: http://plnkr.co/edit/TjTAjc?p=info

Comment: @ViktorEriksson I have just edited my response. There is a working example.